# cocos2d + GKMatchmakerViewController causes portrait mode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, orientation, gamekit

I'm implementing Game Kit in a cocos2d game project.

The game is landscape orientation only. And so should gamekit also be.

When I present the gamekit modal viewcontroller for matchmaking, it displays in landscape. But the underlying cocos2d CCLayer becomes portrait.

The rootViewContollers orientation code looks like this:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

//
// There are 2 ways to support auto-rotation:
//  - The OpenGL / cocos2d way
//   - Faster, but doesn't rotate the UIKit objects
//  - The ViewController way
//  - A bit slower, but the UiKit objects are placed in the right place
//

#if GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationNone
//
// EAGLView won't be autorotated.
// Since this method should return YES in at least 1 orientation,
// we return YES only in the Portrait orientation
//
return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );

#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationCCDirector
//
// EAGLView will be rotated by cocos2d
//
// Sample: Autorotate only in landscape mode
//
if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
} else if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
}

// Since this method should return YES in at least 1 orientation,
// we return YES only in the Portrait orientation
return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation) );

#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
//
// EAGLView will be rotated by the UIViewController
//
// Sample: Autorotate only in landscpe mode
//
// return YES for the supported orientations

return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );

#else
#error Unknown value in GAME_AUTOROTATION

#endif // GAME_AUTOROTATION


// Shold not happen
return NO;
}
```

It makes no difference if I define GAME_AUTOROTATION to kGameAutorotationUIViewController or kGameAutorotationCCDirector or kGameAutorotationNone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe I have found a fix.

In my AppDelegate I made these changes:

```
//[window addSubview: viewController.view];
[window setRootViewController:viewController];
```

Then orientation worked perfectly on iOS6, but on iOS versions prior to iOS6 the width and height of the window size was reversed, and caused issues for the game. I solved that by adding a blank scene before running my normal scene, because the reverse size was fixed by itself when pushing a new scene. From the blank scene I ran [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceWithScene:[Game scene]]; after a delay, and it works now.